# delete join nested query

Tags: mysql

i have table VIDEO with cols (url, title, desc, ...) and table FAVORITE with cols(fav_url, thumb).

when i try to delete rows from both tables using:

```
delete from video join favorite on video.url=favorite.fav_url
  where url in (select url from video where title like '%thumb%')
```

i get error.

is there any way to do this job executing one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** TRY THIS NOW

YOU CANT ACTUALLY DO THIS TYPE OF DELETE QUERY WHEN YOU HAVE A SUB QUERY LIKE YOU DO.
Read this article which explains more in detail.

[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

```
DELETE video, favorite 
    FROM video
    JOIN favorite 
        ON video.url = favorite.fav_url
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT url 
                  FROM video 
                  WHERE title like '%thumb%') tt ON video.url = tt.url
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'V' for update in FROM clause

Comment: WHAT THE? Did you use the exact code above? did you have anything in the Query window at the same time? I just wrote a query nearly identitical and got no error at all.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: ur edited version: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'video' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Found a URL that i have added to my answer, it explains why you cant do that type of update when you have a Subquery like you do.

Comment: I have reposted the SQL with a change to the IN WHERE Statement.

Comment: ;) Glad to hear, got there at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM video t1 JOIN favorite t2 ON t1.url=t2.fav_url
WHERE url IN
    (SELECT url FROM (SELECT * FROM video) t3 WHERE title LIKE '%thumb%')
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause